# Can't remount with new options in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a partition /dev/sdb8 with ext4 filesystem on it.

At first I mounted it with usrquota,grpquota options in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdb8  /quota    ext4  usrquota,grpquota   0  0 

mount /quota 

mount # I can see it is mounted correctly
```

Then I tried to remount it but only with "defaults" option in /etc/fstab :

```
/dev/sdb8  /quota   ext4    defaults  0 0 


mount -o remount /quota
mount # Not what I expected
```

But after last `mount` command I still can see usrquota,grpquota options.

Any ideas why is it like that ?

Comment: But after last mount command I still can see usrquota,grpquota options. ::WHERE ?

Comment: It 's in the code-part of the question. This line :
`mount # Not what I expected`